# Closure or prototype model for charting library

Tags: javascript, performance, d3.js

For Developing javascript charting library, Which model is best prototype or closure??
While developing chart library which includes more intraction and animation, Does encapsulation necessary?

Like here,

```
function main(){
 var w = 100;

 function chart(){
  //main chart rendering
 }
 chart.width = function(){}
 chart.regenerate = function(){}
 chart.sort = function(){}
 chart.updatelegend = function(){}
 chart.startanimation = function(){}
return chart;
}
```

Is this a valid case to use javascript closure like this?

Comment: Always start by writing down how you expect your clients to work with your objects. It gives a great insight on how to design things. However here I can definitely tell the design is very wrong. How do you expect to create new `chart` instances? Sure you can `new chart()`, but these objects will have none of the expect instance functions.

Comment: This is just a sample flow model of closure pattern. I will create new instance by var mychart = new main(data);mychart.width();Like this. or else should i go with prototypal pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about your domain, but here's an example of what you could do:

```
//define the 'charts' module
var charts = (function () {

    //Chart constructor
    function Chart() {
    }

    Chart.prototype = {
        constructor: Chart,

        //public Chart API
        width: function () { /*...*/ }
    };

    //public module members
    return {
        Chart: Chart
    };
})();

//using it
var chart = new charts.Chart();
```

If you need priviledged members, you can always rely on closures, but I do not recommend it because it's less memory-efficient (instances aren't sharing functions).

E.g.

```
function Chart(width) {
    var _width = width; //private var

    //priviledged function
    this.width = function () { return _width ; };
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i exactly looking for, Actually i am in a process of   developing a framework for all chart types, my question is can i add any kind of methods like UpdateChart(), Sort() etc... with public chart API. Also can you please explain why it is not recommend to use Closure methods?..... Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user2787211 Yes, there is no limit on what you can put on the prototype and I updated the second part of my answer. You can go read about it by researching the subject, there's a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code ,am not using Prototype as you used. Is there any difference between both the codes.Any way both will return same Object.Is there any difference in handling objects

```
var charts = (function () {

    //Chart constructor
    function Chart() {
        console.log(this.width())
    }

    Chart.constructor = function() {
    }
    Chart.width = function(){
    }

    };

    //public module members
    return Chart

    })();

//using it
var chart = new charts.Chart();
```